# Program layout - creating aptly sized arrays through System.in.read

Tags: java, arrays, loops

The following is obviously very impractical but my lecturer insists on teaching us a very fundamental understanding of programming. The exercise he gave us goes like this:

*Using only System.in.read, int, char, and loops, create a method that reads
   user input from the command line and returns a char[] that's exactly as big as the amount
   of characters that were entered. Do not use System.arraycopy() or other library methods.*

I'm clueless. Since there seems to be no way of buffering System.in.read input, the array would have to be perfectly sized before any chars are parsed. How in the world is this supposed to work?

Comment: Find out how many characters were entered. Created a char array that size. Not sure what the issue is. (What's wrong with insisting on a very fundamental understanding of programming?)

Comment: I think he intends for you to do your own custom buffering. You are not restricted to making one char array and only one char array.

Comment: You can't buffer the content if you have just `System.in.read`, `int`, `char` and loops - no Objects (lists, ...) or arrays. But "*and returns a char[] that's exactly as big as the amount of characters*" does not require that IMO. So just count the characters you get from the input, create a new empty `char[]` and return that.

Comment: Well, you can abuse recursion to buffer http://ideone.com/PiHr7C but I doubt that your task is to come up with something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a method that reads user input from the command line and returns a char[]

On a second thought, I assume that you are supposed to do your own input buffering by growing a `char[]` array yourself. That should be the reason why `System.arraycopy()` is mentioned.

Growing an array works like

- create a new array that is 1 item longer than the existing one.
- for each character in the old array

  - copy the character from the old to the new array, keeping the position
- replace the old array with grown array.

If you combine that with a loop that reads all characters from the inputstream you get about the following and should be done with your assignment.

- start with array of length 0
- while character available from inputstream

  - grow the array one larger
  - put the character from inputstream into the last slot of the array
- return array

---

It is even possible to do it without loops and growing arrays. Just creating a new array of the correct size once.

```
private static char[] readToCharArray(int length) throws IOException {
    int read = System.in.read();
    char[] result;
    if (read == -1 || read == '\r' || read == '\n' ) {
        result = new char[length];
    } else {
        result = readToCharArray(length + 1);
        result[length] = (char) read;
    }
    return result;
}

char[] myArray = readToCharArray(0);
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! Let's hope the prof doesn't try this with huge amounts of data ;)

Comment: @JonasAdler It's an embedded hint to look here for the source of the solution. Just tested, works for me up to length of 5438

Comment: So the prof would have to do a whole lot of typing before it breaks. +1 for this one. A very nice example of recursion

Answer (score 0):

what about manual arraycopy, the text doesn't say anything about that? if that is allowed you could do something like this:

```
    private static char[] readInput() throws IOException {
      System.out.println("type something terminated with '|'");
      char[] input = new char[0];
      int count = 0;
      int read;
      for (; ; ) {
        read = System.in.read();
        if (read == '|') {
          break;
        } else {
          char[] tmp = new char[input.length + 1];
          for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            tmp[i] = input[i];
          }
          input = tmp;
        }
        input[count] = (char) read;
        count++;
      }
      return input;
    }
```

you could also check for `read == -1` instead of `read == '|'` but the end-of-input character differs from system to system. Instead of copying the char[] on every iteration you could also do it every x iterations and then at the end create an array of the correct size. You could also use a while loop...

But it would be definitely more fun to just return an empty array of the correct size as `zapl` suggested :)

Comment: "the end-of-input character differs from system to system" - What does that have to do with anything? InputStream#read() always returns -1 when the end of the stream is reached. It says so on the javadoc.

Comment: The thing is that if you type in stuff on the console you need to know the end-of-input character in order to make `System.in.read()` return `-1`

Comment: I suppose, if you're not into using pipes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your lecturer meant:

- The char[] should contain the characters that were read from System.in (not just be the right size)
- "`System.in.read`" refers only to `InputStream#read()` and not to the other overloaded `read` methods on `InputStream`, so you're constrained to reading one character at a time.

You should look at the way `ArrayList` is implemented. It is backed by an array, yet the list is arbitrarily resizable. When the size of the list exceeds the array size, `ArrayList` creates a new array that is larger, and then copies the contents of the old array into it. Here are some relevant excerpts from `ArrayList`:

```
/**
 * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
 *
 * @param e element to be appended to this list
 * @return <tt>true</tt> (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 */
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}

private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    modCount++;
    // overflow-conscious code
    if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
        grow(minCapacity);
}

/**
 * Increases the capacity to ensure that it can hold at least the
 * number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.
 *
 * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
 */
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

Since you can't use `System.arraycopy()`, you'll need to write your own method to do that. That's just a `for` loop.

This isn't actually all that inefficient. As the javadoc describes, `ArrayList#add(E)` runs in amortized constant time.

If you follow the `ArrayList` strategy exactly, then your resulting array will be larger than it needs to be, so at the end, you'll need to do one more array resize at the end to truncate it to exactly the input size. Alternately, you could just grow the array by 1 every time you read a character, but the running time will be quadratic (n^2) rather than linear (n) in the input length.